# Jobs in kubernetes - what are they for?

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine

All

have kubernetes on Google Computing Engine running, launching pods etc.

Recently learned that in Kubernetes Jobs were added as first class construct.

Could someone enlighten me why they were added? Looks like another level of indirection, but to solve exactly WHAT kind of problems which pods and replication controller were unable to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jobs are for workloads designed for tasks that will run to completion, then exit.

It is technically still a pod, just another kind. Where a pod while start up and run continuously until it's terminated or it crashes, a job will run a workload, then it will exit with a "Completed" status.

There is also a cronJob type, which will run periodically on set times. If you think of how cronJobs work on a standard Linux system, it should give you an idea of how you might utilize jobs (or cronJobs) on your k8s cluster

Comment: thank you for the answer, but it is still a bit unclear. If I run pod with RC and proper restart policy, it will run to completion, I see no difference here. Yes, cronJobs add some functionality, that's good...

Comment: it won't run to completion. A normal pod that 'stop'/'complete'/'exit' is a failure, it will be rescheduled somewhere else and start again. A job expect the pod to exit, depending on the exit value the job will be marked as success or failed. In case of success it won't be rescheduled.